# Configure AVG free to work with logmein.com free

Tags: windows-8, avg-antivirus, logmein

The Logmein.com free version works with my windows 8 pro pc. But when I install AVG free, it stops working.

The logmein icon on the taskbar appears with a red 'x' next to it. When I click 'switch on logmein', I get a request to run program that requires admin approval. I click yes. Then nothing happens.

If I go to the event log, I see the following event:

Log Name:      Application
Source:        LogMeIn
Event ID:      113
Task Category: General
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          SYSTEM
Description:
Startup of the HTTP Listener subsystem failed with error code 0x0000271d.
Event Xml:

  
    
    113
    2
    1
    0x80000000000000
    
    36953
    Application
    Nassau
    
  
  
    HTTP Listener
    0x0000271d

I tried disabling my AVG antivirus, disabling my zonealarm firewall, and turning off my Spybot SD Resident, but none resolve the problem.

THe only information I found on this error online is http://forums.avg.com/us-en/avg-forums?sec=thread&act=show&id=221885.

How can I configure AVG free to work with logmein.com?

Comment: you should contact the AVG support. Why should we be able to fix a compatibility issue with 2 3rd party tools?

Comment: In this post, there is a comment by apparently a support person of logmein...that says "Why should we be able to fix a compatibility issue with 2 3rd party tools"...to whomever wrote this, I got the same answer from the logmein support people...but what they need to understand is that when their software is the only software that doesn't work with something, it is their responsibility to find the issue. When nothing else has the problem, then they need to find out what is causing the issue. I have the same issue with logmein with the purchased version of AVG.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because logmein no longer have a free version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's AVG's firewall causing this.

1. Open AVG
2. On the Tools menu, click "Firewall settings."
3. In the left tree menu under Profiles, expand the profile you are currently using.
4. Click "System services."
5. Click "Manage user system rules," and then click Add.
6. In the new window, for "protocol," select "TCP"
7. For "direction," select "Both ways," and then click OK.
8. For "local port(s)," click "User selected ports; check a port in the list or add your own to the edit box", type "3389", then click OK.
9. For "remote port(s)," enter "3389", then click OK.
10. For "remote address(es)," select "All Networks," and then click OK.
11. Confirm all windows by clicking OK.

This should fix it. If not- you can start by disabling the firewall component to verify this is the source of the problem- then tinker with the settings yourself to make it work. Personally I avoid AVG now anyway (too bloated) but if I do have to install it, I opt out of pretty much all the optional components- only interested in the "Resident Shield" component of AVG (it's real-time AV scanner).

Comment: AVG free doesn't have a firewall! When I open it, the firewall button has a label 'activate now', which when I click on it, prompts me to purchase it. AVG free isn't what it used to be... Suggested a better free AV that works with Logmein wasn't the answer I was expecting, but I guess it would be good to enough to mark as answer!

Comment: Actually AVG does work great with Logmein! Here's the fix: 1) uninstall AVG 2) reboot 3) reinstall AVG, but make sure you choose "basic protection" not the trial of the Pro version, then choose "Custom install", and opt OUT of every component (the CORE real-time component is always installed and not shown as an option here). The desktop gadget and Outlook plugins help AVG promote their product more than anything else. Identity protection doesn't work- it's just another brainchild of their marketing dept. Anyway, this should fix it! Keep AVG lean and it's decent but default settings are brutal!